# Aufnahmetest, Aufnahmeverfahren und Aufnahmeprüfung

Tags: synonym

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen Aufnahmetest, Aufnahmeverfahren und Aufnahmeprüfung oder sind das Synonyme?
Danke im Voraus!

Comment: Inwiefern wird das nicht von einem Wörterbuch erklärt? Ich betrachte die Frage in der gegenwärtigen Form als off-topic.

Comment: Hi Vampire Slayer! Herzlich Willkommen hier bei german.SE. Ich habe die Frage erstmal geschlossen, aus dem von guidot genannten Grund. Falls sich die Frage nicht mit einem Wörterbuch beantworten lässt, kannst du die Frage editieren und beschreiben, wo das Problem liegt. Dann öffne ich die Frage gern wieder.

Answer (score 3):

Aufnahme*test* und Aufnahme*prüfung* sind Synonyme, denn "Test" ist nur ein (englisches) Fremdwort für "Prüfung".

Aufnahme*verfahren* hingegen ist nicht notwendigerweise mit einer Prüfung (oder einem Test) verbunden: das Aufnahmeverfahren zB. eines Fußballklubs kann darin bestehen, einen Mitgliedsantrag auszufüllen, den Vereinsbeitrag zu entrichten, etc.. Als "Aufnahmeverfahren" würde ich definieren:

> Alle Aktivitäten, die für eine Aufnahme (in was auch immer) notwendig sind.

Das kann durchaus eine AufnahmePrüfung beinhalten, muß es aber nicht.

Comment: Ich möchte die Aufmerksamkeit auf  [diese Meta Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/beantworten-von-off-topic-fragen) richten.